# Correct arrow notation for function with natural domain

Tags: functions

I saw a definition stating that given a function $f:X \to Y$ the natural domain of $f$ is the largest possible subset $D \subseteq X$ for which the rule defining $f$ is valid.

From what I understand, the $X$ in $f:X \to Y$ must be the domain of $X$. Let’s suppose $D$ is a subset of $X$ but is not $X$ itself, then that seems to imply that there is at least one element in $X$ not in $D$. But if $X$ contains an element not in the domain of $f$ then we can’t write $f:X \to Y$. If such a subset $D$ exists and is not $X$, then that implies $f$ is not a function in the first place.

My question is: is this definition flawed? Or, when written in arrow notation, is it acceptable for $X$ to be a set containing the domain; even if it is not the domain of the function itself?

Comment: Can you tell us where you saw that definition.  That must be a text that has an alternative definition of function.  One where a function is defined by a *rule* not an statement of the domain and image of domain and where the domain is not given. For example if you were told $f(x)=\sin x$ and not told anything about what the actual domain is, all reals? some reals? I *guess* what the are getting at is the "natural domain" is $[0,2\pi)$ as that's "enough".  Although.... enough for what.  I *don't* like this definition but I imagine it *is* consistent *within its own context*.

Comment: From nearly all other texts and from most mathematicians point of view "natural" domain has no meaning and a function has a domain which is nothing more nor less than what we *say* it is.  So if we define a function as $f:X\to Y$ we mean $X$ *is* the domain.  This definition *seems* to think we sometimes do things like say $\arcsin: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and we define the "natural" domain as $[-1,1]\subset \mathbb R$ and $x\in [-1,1]$ is the only time $\arcsin$ is valid. But... that assumes saying $\arcsin:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ was valid in the first place.

Comment: @fleablood The book we’re using is a pdf the instructor created for the course. Its definition is: Let $X \in \mathbb R$ and $Y \in \mathbb R$. A real valued function is a relation between the set of inputs $X$ and the set of outputs $Y$, such that any $x \in X$ corresponds to exactly one element from the output set $y \in Y$. This is written as $f: X \to Y$. It also says $X$ is defined to be the domain of $f$.

Comment: @Cdizzle Did you really mean $X\in\mathbb R$, or is it supposed to be $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ instead? Either way, what you wrote in the previous comment agrees with the second paragraph of your question and contradicts the first paragraph.

Comment: Yeah, that definition sounds like we *want* to have a function $f$ but we don't know what the domain $X \subset \mathbb R$ is. We know we can make $X$ as restricted as we'd like but want to find $X$ if it is as "unrestricted" as it can be.  I think a valid definition would be.  If $f(x)$ is *formula* then then "natural domain" of $f(x)$ is the largest possible subset, $X$ of $\mathbb R$ so that $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is a valid and well-defined function.  So if $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ then $X=[0,\infty)$ makes $f:X\to$ a valid function. But $X = (-1,\infty)$ does not.

Comment: @David K sorry, I did indeed mean $X \subseteq \mathbb R$

Comment: ... but you are correct.  To my mind saying for "$\sqrt{}:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a function" is simply wrong.  But saying:  "if $\sqrt{}:X \to \mathbb R$ is a function, and $X\subset R$ is the largest possible subset so that it is, then $X=[0,\infty)$ is the *natural domain* of $\sqrt{}$" *is* a valid thing to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking way too long about this I'd say scrub the definition as given as you are correct: the notation "$f:X\to Y$ is function" *does* imply $X$ is the domain and the definition *doesn't* make sense.

But replace it with this:

> If $f$ is a rule that can map some elements of $X$ to $Y$, and then the *natural domain* is the largest subset $D\subseteq X$ so that $f:D\subseteq X \to Y$ is a valid function. (i.e. in that $D$ is an acceptable domain and all elements of $D$ can be mapped and all elements of $X\setminus D$ *can't* be.)

That way we avoid saying the *incorrect* "$f:X\to Y$ is a function" (it *isn't*... that fails the definition of function) and avoid any weird and awkward "$f:X\to Y$ but not as *function* maps... we just mean *some* of the $X$ *can* be mapped"

========

I guess what the book is getting at is if you take a naive idea of function being a "rule" and there is some universal set we are working in then saying things like

$f(x) = \frac {x^2 +7}{x-3}$ or $h(x) = \arcsin x$ or $j(x) = \sqrt x$

and we make the naive and blanket statement that all theses are real functions and map $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Then the "unnatural" super-general-not-much thought put into "domain" of all these functions are $\mathbb R$.

ANd so the *natural* domain is the one's where the function actually *works*.  "Natural" domain of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb R\setminus \{3\}$.  Naural domain of $h$ is $[-1,1]$. and natural domain $j(x)$ is $[0,\infty)$.

But the thing is a real "grown-up" mathematician would never say $\mathbb R$ is the domain.  They'd simply say the if $f(x)$ isn't valid then $x$ is simply not in the domain. Period.

Unless.... well if this is practical math text.

Suppose I told you "I have function and it maps reals to reals and the function is $f(x) = \sqrt{x^3 - 57x} + \frac 1{\sqrt{431- x^2}}$ and I need to know what the domain is" well, the technical answer is the domain can be what I want it to be.  If I want the domain to be $\{0,-1, -2,-3\}$ so that $f(x)= \begin{cases}\frac 1{\sqrt {431}}&x=0\\\sqrt{56}+\frac 1{\sqrt{430}}&x=-1\\\sqrt{106}+\frac 1{427}&x=-2\\12 +\frac 1{\sqrt{422}}&x=-3\end{cases}$

well, then I *can* have $f:\{0,1,2,3\}\to \mathbb R$ via $f(x) =\sqrt{x^3 - 57x} + \frac 1{\sqrt{431- x^2}}$.  But that's not what I *meant*.

So then I say "C'mon.... you know what I mean.... I want the biggest set of real numbers that can be the domain.... I want the....um, let's call it 'natural domain'" and then .. well that *is* a legitimate question.

To define the *function* $f: X \to \mathbb R$ I must specify what the domain $X$ is.

But do I *really* have to?  Do I really have to say... "well we need $x^3 - 57 \ge 0$ and we need $431 -x^2 > 0$ so the means $x$ must be between...."  Do I even care?

Why shouldn't I just say:  Let $f: NaturalDomain(\sqrt{x^3 - 57x} + \frac 1{\sqrt{431- x^2}})\subset R\to \mathbb R$. and not really *worry* about knowing *what* values of $x$ that $ \sqrt{x^3 - 57x} + \frac 1{\sqrt{431- x^2}}$ id defined on?

Comment: I think I understand. So am I right in thinking this idea trying to be communicated is less formal and more intuitive, but it is being communicated in a formal manner that appears to be slightly flawed? The definition as presented confused me because it made me think I had misunderstood functions and their notation.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical notations are mostly a matter of conventions and ultimately the understanding of notations depends very much on the *context*.

Sometimes people write $f:X\to Y$ while $X$ means a set that *contains* the domain of $f$ and the author explicitly denotes the domain of $f$ with $D$, which is a proper subset of $X$. Sometimes people make a combination and write something like
$$
f:D(f)\subset \mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}
$$
where $D(f)$ denotes the domain of $f$.

Mostly when people write $f:X\to Y$, $X$ means the domain of $f$.

---

If you assume *in the first place* that $X$ *is* the domain of $f$, *and* write $f:X\to Y$, then it never happens that "$X$ contains an element not in the domain of $f$".

If $B$ is a proper subset of $X$, which is *assumed* to be the domain of $f$, then it is true that $X$ has an element that is not in $B$. This does not contradict anything about the definition of the domain of $f$: your domain of $f$ is $X$, not $B$.

Think about the following example.

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function defined on $X=[0,1]$. Then

- $B=[0,1)$ is a (proper) subset of $X$.
- $X$ contains an element that is not in $B$, i.e., $x=1$.

Comment: I think you mean $B=[0,1)$.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz ah, yes, thanks! Fixed.

Comment: You said that if $B$ is a proper subset of $X$ then it doesn’t contradict anything about $X$ being the domain, but I still don’t understand why? In the definition, $B$ is said to be the largest subset for which the rule defining $f$ is valid. If that is true, then in your example $f$ does not map $1$ to $Y$ because if it did, then $B$ would not be the largest subset for which the rule defining $f$ is valid; $X$ would be the largest subset.

Comment: @Cdizzle: When you say "B is a subset of X" you don't have any information about it, not "  is said to be the largest subset for which the rule defining  is valid". I don't see that. All you said is "Let’s suppose  is a subset of  but is not  itself".// That is what *definition* is used for: when you talk about something, you have to stick to one version of the definition, instead of jumping back and forth.

Comment: I have never in my life seen someone write $f: X \to Y$ where the domain is not all of $X$. Do you have an example of this occurring?

Comment: @Randall: that was indeed quite rare, I have seen such notation used in seminars... The notation $f:D(f)\subset X\to Y$ is quite common; it is used for instance in Hunter-Nachtergaele's Applied Analysis.

Comment: That seems horribly self-referential.

Comment: @mrsamy my apologies, I accidentally wrote $B$ when I meant $D$. I have corrected the question.

My confusion is that if $D$ is the largest subset of $X$ for which the rule holds, then $D$ would always be $X$ which seems like an odd definition to me? I should also note that the book explicitly defines $X$ as the domain, not simply a set containing the domain.

Comment: "I have never in my life seen someone write f:X→Y where the domain is not all of X. Do you have an example of this occurring?"  I have seen high school algebra texts that ask "what is the domain of $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 37}$?" assuming we want the domain to be large a subset as the real numbers as we can have.  I think that is what this definition is getting at.